# 1366x768 native display resolution on a GT720m - battery life + performance advantage over 1080?

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, hardware-rec

So I am aware that the GT720m can handle resolutions a lot higher than 1366x768. -  up to 2560x1600.
My laptop is coming with a 1366x768 as it's native and max resolution due to the display/led hardware they are using. 
The Lenovo U530 has 2 types of displays, one that is 1366x768 and the other is 1080x1920.   the Lenovo Canada website only has the 1366 gimped models.
So my question is, will the video card (GT720M) on the laptop perform better at a lower resolution than it would on a 1080 resolution??

Comment: I am guessing no one knows the answer to this? Or is this (superuser) the wrong site to ask?

Comment: It might take longer then 2 a few days to answer.  In the end we cannot really predict the performance of a laptop we don't have access to.  The card might support it, if the display does not, then the higher resolution is only important for external displays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody answered this. As I'm sure you've found out by now, your Lenovo U530 actually has two GPUs in it - the GT720m dedicated card, and the Intel HD graphics on your CPU. Your laptop, like most modern laptops with this configuration, can switch between using the more efficient Intel GPU and the more powerful Nvidia GPU using the "[optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html)" technology. While running off the Intel GPU, you can achieve a maximum resolution of 1366x768, while the GT720m can achieve 1920x1080 or above (on external monitors).

It is more efficient to use the Intel HD graphics solution, and thus using that mode will result in longer battery life. This is not only because of its efficiency-focused design, but also because it runs off the CPU die, and thus no additional wattage is required. The GT720m die can be completely shut down while the Intel HD chip is providing display.